Angular PrimeNG p-dropdown dirty by default
I'm encountering an issue with PrimeNG Dropdown component in version 13.4.1 where it appears to be dirty by default, even when no selections have been made.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
<p-dropdown
    [autoDisplayFirst]="false"
    resetFilterOnHide="true"
    id="allergyid"
    formControlName="allergyid"
    tooltip="Allergy Name"
    styleClass="form-control"
    [options]="pamAlgseverity"
    optionLabel="description"
    optionValue="id"
    placeholder="Allergy"
    [virtualScroll]="true"
    [itemSize]="31"
    [filter]="true"
    [showClear]="true">
</p-dropdown>

I'd like to find a solution to prevent the dropdown from displaying as dirty until a user interacts with it. However, I need to stick with version 13.4.1 for this particular project and cannot upgrade or downgrade.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Double check that you are not changing the formControl after the component shows in the template. If you are, consider using ngIf on the component until after those changes are done.

Thanks for the response, the issue i am facing is the formcontrol gets initialized prior to the API call, which results in form control getting dirty. What i am trying to figure out is a way to get this issue sorted. If i use async or set a timeout to the formcontrol then it does work as intended but is there any way to do it without using those two

@Nash Based on your comment, I would prevent the form from loading in the template until after the API call has resolved. Depending on what version of Angular you are using, you can use an *ngIf or control flow syntax.

Thanks for the response will try this solution as well, with the latest ng version this issue seems to be sorted
